# Prevent default on link if parent hasClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, parent, preventdefault

Simplified HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="no-link"><a>Should not be clickable</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Should be clickable</a></li>
            <li><a>Should be clickable</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

    $('a').parent().click(function(e) {
        if($(this).hasClass('no-link')){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

Works fine on the link that should not be clickable, but also affects the two descendant `a` tags. Why? I thought `parent()` only traversed up a single step in the DOM.

I'm adding the class programatically via WordPress (as an option in the Appearance > Menus control panel), so targeting the `a` tag directly via class is not really an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to actually capture the click on `a` element and then check for parent class inside it.

Just change your code to:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
     if($(this).parent().hasClass('no-link')){
         e.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

Comment: Ah. I knew it was something simple and obvious, but I just wasn't seeing it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
    $('li > a').click(function(e) {
        if($(this).parent().hasClass('no-link')){
            console.log('parent has class no-link')
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="no-link"><a href="#">Should not be clickable</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Should be clickable</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Should be clickable</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"I thought parent() only traversed up a single step in the DOM."*

It does. But you are attaching your click handler to the parent, and click events bubble up from the clicked item through their parent, the parent's parent, etc., and can be cancelled anywhere along that chain. So your code cancel all clicks for all anchors within that parent element.

Try this instead:

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
   if($(this).parent().hasClass('no-link')){
     e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

That is, handle the click event at the anchor level, testing the parent of the clicked item.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is the best - just stop propagation:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('a').parent().click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); // Preventing from event bubbling and capturing
        if($(this).hasClass('no-link')){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: No, that's not a good solution. `stopPropagation` disrupts the event flow, it's also an invitation for trouble in case you want to add some event listeners to any of the ancestors and it's really hard to debug if you forget that you've added `stopPropagation`

Comment: @strah I used stopPropagation just for this certain case, but you have right - if this code will be extended, stopPropagation may cause problems.